# Friend function still can't access private member

Tags: c++, namespaces, friend, friend-function

I have a simple C++ class, which I'm trying to add stream operators to, so it can be used with `cout` and `cin`

```
#include <iostream>

namespace testing_namespace {
    class test {
        friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const test &o);
        friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, test &o);
    public:
        void doThing();
    private:
        int member;
    };
}
```

This is the implementation file:

```
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const testing_namespace::test &o) {
    return os << o.member;
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, testing_namespace::test &o) {
    return is >> o.member;
}

void testing_namespace::test::doThing() {
    std::cout << member << " thing" << std::endl;
}
```

I'm getting an error on compilation:

```
In function 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const testing_namespace::test&)':
test.cpp:8:20: error: 'int testing_namespace::test::member' is private within this context
 return os << o.member;
```

with a similar error for `operator>>`. The `doThing` method compiles with no issues.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here - shouldn't friend functions be able to access the private members of the class `test`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define those functions under the namespace too. When you do that, you can omit the name of the namespace from `test`.

```
namespace testing_namespace 
{
  std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const test &o) {
    return os << o.member;
  }

  std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, test &o) {
    return is >> o.member;
  }
}
```

Comment: You no longer need to type `testing_namespace::test` in the parameter list. Just `test` will be fine.

Comment: @Carl, true. BTW, I don't know why you deleted your answer. It's perfectly ok to see two answers that have the same solution.

Comment: To make it clearer for future visitors to the post. Figured it would be more organized to have a single answer since they were pretty much the same.